# which method of model to update the row in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i have trouble in creating method in controller of cakephp to update the my existing row in a table, can anyone suggest me appropriate model method to update the row in table

```
<?php 
class UsersController extends AppController
{
public function update($id)
  {
      if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
      {
        // method of model to update the row    
      }
     else
     $this->set('user',$this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id))));
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Reading the documentation helps. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html Do the blog tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array

```
$this->User->id = $id;
$this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the code.......

<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function update($id = null) {
        if ($id) {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->User->id = $id;
                $this->User->save($this->request->data);
            } else {
                $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id))));
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@burzum after reading the tutorial which link provide by you i found the solution to the my problem, in model **updateAll()** method available in model by using this i have update row of the table.

```
public function update($id)
  {
      if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
      {
            $this->User->id=$id;
            if($this->User->updateAll(array('User.fname'=>"'".$_REQUEST['fname']."'",'User.lname'=>"'".$_REQUEST['lname']."'",'User.email'=>"'".$_REQUEST['email']."'"),array('id'=>$id)))
                echo '<script>alert("update successfully")</script>';
            else
                echo '<script>alert("failes to update ")</script>';
      }
      else
        $this->set('user',$this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id))));
  }
```